# How to query record type repeated field in google big query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In my big query table, I just added another record type field say "B" inside record type field "A". In standard SQL dialect, I am unable to query repeated fields of B as-
select A.B.field1, A.B.field2, ... from  where _partitiontime = ;

for following query-

```
SELECT ad_request_custom_targeting.iom.size, 
ad_request_custom_targeting.iom.bidprice FROM `nyt-adtech- 
prd.dfp_data.dfp_log_network_requests` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2019- 
05-03" LIMIT 1000
```

I get error as-
    Cannot access field size on a value with type  "ARRAY>" at [1:40]

Answer (score 4):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

I assume that in your example

`A` is `ad_request_custom_targeting` and `B` is `iom`

```
SELECT B.size, B.bidprice 
FROM `nyt-adtech-prd.dfp_data.dfp_log_network_requests`,
  UNNEST(ad_request_custom_targeting) A,
  UNNEST(A.iom) B 
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2019-05-03" 
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: for this query, I get validation error in standard sql dialect as-   Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRUCT<mnetSize STRING, mnet_rpc STRING, col STRING, ...>

Comment: You should update your question with exact schema of your data. My answer is based on the limited info you gave so far!